# Resolve type binding is always null in Assignment and VariableDeclarationFragment ASTParser

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am developing stand alone java application using the `ast parser eclipse api`. I am trying to extract the type bindings for fields and method declarations. The logic for doing that is inside my parser and Visitor class (see below).

```
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(parseFile);
    parser.setUnitName(fileName);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setEnvironment(null,null, null, true);
    CompilationUnit compilationUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null); // parse
    return compilationUnit;
```

And visitor class

```
  for (final TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration : allTypes) {
        typeDeclaration.accept(new ASTVisitor() {           
            @Override
            public boolean visit(final Assignment node) {
                addLogs("Assignment Node type :- "+node);
                ITypeBinding iTypeBinding = node.resolveTypeBinding();      
                .............
             }
         });

           @Override
           public  boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
              if(node == null || node.getInitializer() == null) return super.visit(node);
            final IVariableBinding iVariableBinding = node.resolveBinding();
            if(iVariableBinding == null) return super.visit(node);
            ITypeBinding iTypeBinding = node.getName().resolveTypeBinding();
            ..............
            }
          });
```

But the resolve binding is always null so I can't get the variable name and fully qualify the class type of variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Environment in ASTParser `setEnvironment(classPath,sourcePath,contentType,true)`. Here classPath is source class file location, sourcePath is source java file location and content type is UTF-8.